SQL Connection Failed after switch the Azure SQL failover group
I use Entity Framework to connect to an Azure SQL database. Recently I needed to switch the failover group, but I found there will be lots of  SQL connection issues. After a few hours, I switched the Azure SQL  failover group. I can find some connection error on TCP to failed to return client key, but I have no idea why it related with the Azure SQL failover group.
Error message:

Exception: Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login.
Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server;
the server was too busy to accept new connections;
or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server.
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()


Are you providing correct credentials of database?

System.Data.SqlClient <-- This might be your problem. Instead, try using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (and yes, you can now use MDS with EF6 on .NET Framework 4.8 provided you're using EF 6.5 with Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer). If that doesn't fix it, please share your SQL Server connection-string verbatim (except for the password, of course) - or are you using Managed Identity for passwordless connections? Also, can you connect to the FOG (Failover Group) from outside Azure's network, e.g. from home?

we use .NetFramework 4.72 and EntityFramwork 6.1. could you please help to share why upgrade could resolve the issue?

we build the connection by SqlConnectionStringBuilder
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
builder.ConnectTimeout = timeout;
builder.ConnectRetryCount = maxConnectionRetryCount;
builder.MaxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;

For auth, we use one AAD + certificate in AKV to connect database, when build the connection, we need to get the identity token,  the identity auth token content will be different every time, different token will lead to a new connection opened. To avoid the connection count increase up to the connection pool threshold, I cached the token for one hour, so the connection pool might be reused in one hour. But from log, the sql read-only error only take 2 mins. and then after 2 or 3 hours, I found lots of sql connetion and timeout error. But after switch back the SQL FG, the error were gone.

and we can connect the FOG in SSMS, not all connections failed, more than half connection are successful, but some query for big data might timeout. and there are some error on tcp failed to return client key. to clarify, when I switch back the failover group, there is no more error on query timeout, all of errors are about the tcp issues, it failed on pre-login.

@feili .NET 4.7.2 is really outdated - you need to update to .NET Framework 4.8 (because every OS/platform which ran 4.7.2 will now be running 4.8 or 4.8.1). EF 6.1 is also very old: you're missing out on essential security and performance improvements added since, especially in EF 6.4 - and now 6.5. I assure you the process is painless: you only need to edit a few lines in your .csproj files (and nuke your bin and obj dirs) and then Rebuild (specifically, the <TargetFramework> property, and the <PackageReference> for EF).

Thanks @Dai, I am working on it now, I am curious why higher version could resolve the issue. could you please help to share more details?

@feili To clarify, I'm not asserting that it will fix the problem - it's just an educated hunch - but it is based on my own recent experiences with very similar things breaking due to  bugs in System.Data.SqlClient which were only fixed in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (e.g. TDS MARS errors): I'm a long-time Azure AppServices+AzureSQL customer (since 2012) and this is nothing new.

...and the problem with cloud-y services is that the platform is constantly evolving (i.e. stuff will just break and we have to deal with it) and as an application-developer it's incumbent upon us to keep on the treadmill, which means keeping dependencies/platform-integrations updated.

But let me take a step-back... please post the full StackTrace of that SqlException you're getting there. Also, are you running in Azure AppServices, an isolated ASE, a VM - or something that's running on-prem that's connecting into Azure - or something else? And this is "Azure SQL" (aka the horribly-ambigously-named "SQL Database") and not "Azure SQL Managed Instance" or a self-managed SQL Server install in a VM, right?

yes,  we use Azure SQL database, not the Azure SQL managed Instance,  or SQL server in one VM.

our service connecting SQL is Azure Cloude Service(Extend support)

I found our SQL query duration is pretty longer than the CPU time for one single sql statement, which means the query is waiting till timeout.

updated the question to add more stack trace for error message

When you switch the failover group, the DNS changes might take some time to propagate. During this period of propagation delay, your application might try to connect to the old primary server. Please read more about on Microsoft Documentation.
Please consider implementing a retry logic and increase the connection timeout to help you mitigate the connection issues you're experiencing and help you with transient faults.

Thanks, I don't think retry works, since we have retry logic in our service, but not SQL side.  and I understand there might be some time to propagate the DNS change, but I RDP to the VM running our service, the nslookup result for failover group is right one. and also, I get the timeout&connection error when get data from database, I think it should not be effected by the failover group, since the primary and secondary database are readable. and thanks for the suggestion, I can double confirm if the service still send the request to pervious database

it might be caused connection pool reused. but we got "read-only" error for 2 mins after I switched the failover group, and then everything is good. but after 2 or 3 hours, we got lots of sql connection

If it's DNS issue, it's hard to explain why I switch back the SQL failover group, the timeout issues were gone.
